# How to force any program to close?

Tags: command-line, firefox, kill

Sometimes programs tell me I can't start it because there is already another instance of it running. Best example would be Firefox and Chromium, but this problem accounts for many applications.

I cannot find the applications PID in the running processes.

How to kill all running instances of a program, e.g. Firefox?

I tried:

```
ps ax | grep firefox
```

But everything I can find is:

```
8193 ?        Rl     0:08 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
```

I tried:

```
kill 8193
```

But I get:

```
Process not found
```

Actually, even when Firefox is running accurately, I cannot find its instances in `ps`.

What did I miss?

Comment: With `killall firefox` you will kill it.

Comment: and add a -9 if that doesn't work

Comment: This really hasn't been asked before?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The easiest solution for a program that is not responding would be:

```
killall firefox
```

and if this doesn't work

```
killall -9 firefox
```

and if this still doesn't work, reboot, nothing else will.

For other killall options, see this article on Wikipedia: [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killall)

Answer (score 7):

Check if this works

```
kill -9 `ps -e | grep firefox | cut -b1-6`
```

Comment: So `ps -e | grep firefox` shows me the right process, interesting!

Comment: actually, `pidof` is much easier than this. `pidof firefox` will get you the right proces immediately. So the the solution could be `kill -9 $(pidof firefox)`. ( the use of backticks (\`) is depracated). But I prefer Uri Herrera's solution `killall -9 firefox` which should do exactly the same.

Comment: `sudo kill -9 \`ps -e | grep teamviewer | cut -b1-6\`` worked pidof did not (Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 2):

Also,
to add more functionality to your Ubuntu system
go into settings > keyboard > keyboard shortcuts
click add to add to a new shortcut
call the command forcequit or something
the command is `xkill`
set the shortcut to your choice of buttons
your mouse should turn into a 'x' and it will kill any process you click on

Answer (score 1):

In certain circumstances `kill` and `killall` may not have the desired effect. This can happen, for instance, if the graphical container of a programme goes haywire. In such cases the process must be killed through `xkill`.

Simply open the a command line and run `xkill`. The mouse pointer becomes a cross and the following message appears:

> Select the window whose client you wish to kill with button 1....

Then left-click with the mouse pointer on the window containing the rogue programme.